# Finding routes from set of points using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, gps, routing, linear-referencing

I have lines table (postgis enabled database) representing the streets.

I have collected few gps points along a route and I would like to match it with the streets in order.

**Scenario** - I am jogging along street A followed by street B, street C. Let's say I have 3 gps points collected when I am in running along each of those streets - total 9 points.

My desired output is a list - **[street A,street B,street C]**
**What I have done so far**

> Get street name given a gps point. This is
>   based on closest distance from the point to any street in the
>   vicinity. As expected when there are overlapping streets, the results
>   gets skewed.

**What I think can work**

> Take pair of points and find the street(line)
>   making smallest angle with line connecting the pair of points. If this is a good approach, what should I expect when I make transition from one street to another (like points (3,4) or (6,7) in the scenario)? They might make a smaller angle with another street close by.

Is there a better way to achieve this or can you make my approach more robust?

Answer (score 1):

I think the resolution could be:

1. Draw the line between all points of gps track
2. Simplify line to prevent gps floating while you're standing
3. Explode line to set of lines (cut the line on every point)
4. For every line from set of lines select line from roads in specified maximal distance and specified maximal angle, order by angle between them and limit 1
5. Select distinct from selected roads.

Comment: I am extending on the premise of http://selectoid.wordpress.com/2009/02/13/reprojecting-snapping-point-geometries-onto-a-given-line-geometry-using-postgis/

Comment: The main flaw with regard to the angle I mentioned in my approach(and your point 4) is that that the lines(streets) may not necessarily be linear. So I would have to explode those lines as well to get the correct angle being formed between them.